# RESX file in TFS disappeared

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

I have a resx file in tfs that my co worker can see but i can not. When i log into our online repository, i can see the file just fine (so i am currently assuming it is not a permission error) but when i look for it in source control explorer inside vs its not there. As a result, it will not grab it on a get latest.

As a work around i can download it from the online repository then re-add it to the project. It will see it as an add. When i go to check in, it asks me to resolve the conflict. i selected take version from server then it checked it in and it was still missing in vs. solution explorer.

Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually fixed this by deleting out my old work space and adding a new one

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the file is just not added to the project that you are looking at in the *Solution Explorer*. Click the *Show All Files* icon in the top of the *Solution Explorer* and it should appear in the list of the files if it is actually located in the folder of your project.

[image: Show All Files action in Solution Explorer]

There seems to be some inconsistency between your coworker's project/solution and yours. Either of you could add the missing files to the project and commit it to the repository.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will give this a try and get back to you.

Comment: no it did not appear to fix it. sorry for the delay

Comment: The thing about this suggestion is i did re-add it to the solution then re-checked it in through tfs. after the process, it was still missing inside source control explorer

which is a problem in my original message - wrongly said solution explorer. will edit that. sorry

Comment: no resolution. if i do come up with one i most certainly will